# sensor Sprites showing outside the 3D model using Autodesk-Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are working on the 3D house model with the sensor placement which follows [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/animate_sprites/) documentation. Also, I followed [that](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app) sample code git repository for creating models and placing sprites.

When I rotate that sample 3D model the sensor doesn't fall off the 3D model and it sticks to its place no matter however I rotate the model. But when I rotate my 3D model one sensor is shown outside the model even though it is placed inside.

I have perfectly placed the position of the sensor position:{x:,y:,z:} and bind it to the room.
What can be the problem?

Below is the image:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try turning on 'sensor occlusion' through the API ?
See https://hyperion.autodesk.io for an example

[image]